# Error says a column doesn't exist when it does

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to setup a program I downloaded, and while setting up the database, I ran into this issue

[image: Error Log]

While over in phpMyAdmin, column 'year' has clearly been added.

[image: Column List from phpMyAdmin]

Am I just bad? Is the program broke? or is there an actual issue here? Thanks

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if you fully qualify the reference (as you always should)? `configs.\`year\``

Comment: @MatBailie sadly, nothing changes. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: Then the configs table does NOT contain that column.  Are you sure you don't have multiple different databases or schemas? Such that you're running your code against one, and checking the table (with phpmyadmin) in another?

Comment: I'm going to try hosting the database on my local server and see if that makes a difference. I just reconfirmed that I'm using the right database as well. Thanks again.

Comment: Kindly try to avoid adding images of code

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't exist.  It is defined as an alias in the same `select`, so it is not available for expressions in the `select`.

So, just repeat the expression:

```
(partition by key, year(edited_at), month(edited_at) . . .)
```

Comment: I can't change the code, if that what you are recommending. The code is part of a program which I have no knowledge of how to edit.

Comment: @Dragonaere . . . Well, the program then has a bug and should be producing code like this.

Comment: this is a bug and so report it